# A conditional button

Tags: user-registration, conditional-content, buttons, signup

I wish to add a button to a page of my site that redirects the user to the signup page, if he is not a registered user, and to another page of the site, let's say Test_Page, if he is a registered user. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress provides the `is_user_logged_in()` function for this.

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

You could do something like:

```
<?php

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // show button to Test_Page
} else {
    // show button to registration page
}

?>
```